# JS + sweetalert - insert values from checkbox to input field

Tags: javascript, html, sweetalert

I must select from a window (done with sweetalert2) a row.

[image: first img]

And insert them according to the column in each input of the following image [image: second]

This is the code of the pop up...

```
 function detalleTransf( detalle_transferencia_id, matricula, bancoorigenTransf, cbu_cta_origen, titular_cta_origen, ultimos_digitos_cta_origen) {

        var datosTransferencia = {{ datosTransferencia|json_encode|raw }} ;

        let html = "<html><body>"

        html += "<div class='table-responsive'><table class='table table-hover table-condensed no-border'>" +
            "<tr class='encabezado-tabla'> <td class='text-center'>Seleccionar </td><td class='text-center'> Matricula</td><td class='text-center'> Banco de Origen</td><td class='text-center'>CBU Cuenta Origen</td><td class='text-center'>Titular Cuenta Origen</td><td class='text-center'>Últimos 5 Dígitos Cuenta Origen</td> </tr>";

        for (let row of datosTransferencia) {

            html += "<tr id='algo'><td class='text-center'><div class='radio'><input type='checkbox' name='check' value='value' id='regular' onclick='unCheck(this)' ><label style='display: none'>" + row.detalle_transferencia_id + "</div></label></td>";

            html += "<td class='text-center'>" + matricula + "</td>";

            html += "<td class='text-center'>" + row.transf_banco + "</td>";

            html += "<td class='text-center'>" + row.transf_cbu + "</td>";

            html += "<td class='text-center'>" + row.transf_titular + "</td>";

            html += "<td class='text-center'>" + row.transf_ctaorigen + "</td></tr>";

        }

        html += "</table></div>";

        html += "</body></html>";
        return html;
    };
```

Example:

In the sweetalert window, I select a row with the check, the value of the "banco de origen" column... must go in the second image in the input field "banco de origen"

what i need is a function to insert the data from the window to de input field